# Variation product in WooCommerce and Tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a bit of a predicament in regards to variation products. I have been tasked with showing the tags of each variation whenever a variation is clicked. For example, we have Gold and Silver products, so when a Silver product is clicked the tag needs to change to Silver, so it is clickable and goes to a page with all other Silver-tagged products.

I have tried countless add-ons, custom codes, ACF, you name it, and I cannot find a way to do this. Is this just something that is out of the scope of WooCommerce? Or is there any way to actually achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding product tags are linked to the product not the variation of the product.

The other way of doing this would be to use ACF, give the variation a taxonomy term and then product with that term can be displayed

ACF taxonomy term - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

product variation field - https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/custom-fields-on-woocommerce-product-variations/

Comment: I did try that - but for som reason I was not able to get the custom field data to show on the front-end no matter what I tried. Not sure if it is because of the nature of variation products, that it might cause issues?